# The probability for a group of 6 people to divide into two groups of the same size

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm not quite sure if my calculation is right, so advice and correction would be appreciated.

The question is:

six people need to divide into two groups. they each either reach out with their hand faced up or down. their decision is random and uniformly distributed. So one group consists of people with their hand up, and the other down. what is the probability that the groups are of the same size?

The probability space is $\{0,1\}^6$ so $|\Omega|=64$

The number of options to divide the group into two groups of three is ${6 \choose 3}=20$ ,so the probability for the group to divide themselves to two groups of three is $\frac{20}{64}=\frac{5}{16}$

Is that calculation correct? I'm not quite sure if I should or shouldn't account for the fact two group options should be the same because of the way the people choose how to divide themselves.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"I'm not quite sure if I should or shouldn't account for the fact two group options should be the same because of the way the people choose how to divide themselves."

It sounds like you're referring to the fact that there are two ways to get each split, e.g. with hands $\{1,2,3\}$ up or with hands $\{4,5,6\}$ up. These are distinct in your space of 64 possible outcomes, so you want to count them separately in the numerator too. Your approach does this correctly, because $\binom63$ counts all the different subsets of size 3, and $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{4,5,6\}$ are indeed different sets.